# How to find who changed the user password in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Recently someone changed password of user.So i fetched the results from dba_udit_trails and dba_audit_sessions but i can able to find  return code as 0(successfull login) , 28000(locked) and 1017(invalid username/password).
How do we get the details,who changed password and how returncode prompts if someone changed the password.

All valuable suggestions wouldbe appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow advice in Oracle Support `Doc ID 419942.1`

You can create trigger to deny password changes.

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER pass_change 
   AFTER ALTER on database
      BEGIN
           IF ora_sysevent='ALTER' and ora_dict_obj_type = 'USER' and ora_des_encrypted_password is not null
           THEN
              RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20003,  'You are not allowed to alter password user.');
           END IF;
      END;
/
```

Or you can create the trigger so that every change will be logged into some auxilliary table:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER log_pass_change 
   AFTER ALTER on database
      BEGIN
           IF ora_sysevent='ALTER' and ora_dict_obj_type = 'USER' and ora_des_encrypted_password is not null
           THEN
              INSERT INTO ....
           END IF;
      END;
/
```